# Material Date Picker used in xml (layout) for date range selection

Tags: android, datepicker, material-ui, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I have requirements to display Date Range Picker as part of View. I go through MaterialDatePicker it only shows Dialog and FullScreen, but I haven't found how to part of the layout (XML). I have followed an official link
https://material.io/components/date-pickers/android#using-date-pickers

Comment: how is this related to [android-jetpack-compose]?

Comment: Actually, I am developing a screen in jetpack compose. So I have a search started from Date Rang in jetpack compose.

Comment: The MaterialDatePicker doesn't have a xml. What you are looking for?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti because it's business requirements to show Date Range picker in horizontal with Others business TextView and EditText onTop of this Date Range Picker.